# Visual Studio 2013 refuses to work with Office 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office-2016

I'm trying to create projects in Visual Studio Pro 2013 for use in Office 2016. I know it's [supposed to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594957/office-2016-add-in-development-in-visual-studio-2013), but VSTO seems to insist I need Office 2013.

I've followed several MSDN walkthroughs ([Add-In](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx/), [Document-level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442985.aspx), [custom tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)), and always end up with errors like these:

[image]

[image]

I checked the registry, and my .NET framework is version 4.6.1. I added the runtime and targeting packs for 4.6 and 4.6.1 to Visual Studio, but keep getting the same results.

The errors come up when I get to the "hit F5 to run the project" step. Any suggestions or solutions?

Background: I'm an MS Word forms developer in a corporate environment. Of our 1,000-or-so forms, about 100 of them have custom toolbars, which haven't been available since the ribbon interface after Office 2003. We modify them with a non-networked machine using the old software. I've been tasked with finding a way to regain functionality similar to custom toolbars in Office 2016, our current baseline. The only version of Visual Studio available to me is VSTO Pro 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel Project => Properties => Debug tab => Start external program
Set it into excel 2016
The path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE

If you cannot debug after that, try to attach the process to debug using Visual Studio.